# Use python regex to catch similar strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have 2 strings of form:

```
Beta_Gambus_teta_some_changeable_string_2017.02.1276 and 
Beta_Gambus_teta__some_changeable_string_update_2017.02.1276
```

Example:

```
 Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_2017.02.1276.ctr
 Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr
 Beta_Gambus_teta_tpsedr_2017.02.1276.ctr
 Beta_Gambus_teta_tpesdr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr
 Beta_Gambus_teta_cnmsr_2018.02.1279.ctr 
 Beta_Gambus_teta_cnms_update_2018.02.1279.ctr
```

I need to catch with regex the ones with 'update' in them separated from the ones without 'update' in them.

I'm using `^.+_(.+)\.ctr$` but it is to broad.

Comment: Do all of the strings start with `Beta_Gambus_teta` ?

Comment: why not do `"update" in s`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the following pattern for the update match:

```
Beta_Gambus_teta_[^_]+_update_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.ctr
```

and use this pattern for the non update match:

```
Beta_Gambus_teta_[^_]+_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.ctr
```

Sample script:

```
path = "Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr"
if re.search(r'Beta_Gambus_teta_[^_]+_update_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.ctr', path):
    print("MATCH")
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're not telling us something, regex is not at all needed here...

```py
strings = ["Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_2017.02.1276.ctr",
           "Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr",
           "Beta_Gambus_teta_tpsedr_2017.02.1276.ctr",
           "Beta_Gambus_teta_tpesdr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr",
           "Beta_Gambus_teta_cnmsr_2018.02.1279.ctr",
           "Beta_Gambus_teta_cnms_update_2018.02.1279.ctr"]

with_update = []
no_update = []
for s in strings:
    if "update" in s:
        with_update.append(s)
    else:
        no_update.append(s)
```

Even getting rid of the `if`:

```py
res = ([], [])

for s in strings:
    res["update" in s].append(s)

no_update, with_update = res
```

And both gives:

```
>>> print(with_update)
['Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr', 'Beta_Gambus_teta_tpesdr_update_2017.02.1277.ctr', 'Beta_Gambus_teta_cnms_update_2018.02.1279.ctr']
>>> print(no_update)
['Beta_Gambus_teta_wqtr_2017.02.1276.ctr', 'Beta_Gambus_teta_tpsedr_2017.02.1276.ctr', 'Beta_Gambus_teta_cnmsr_2018.02.1279.ctr']
```

Answer (score 1):

To match strings with `_update_` use:

```
^Beta_Gambus_teta_.*_update_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.ctr$
```

and to match strings without `_update_`:

```
^Beta_Gambus_teta_(?!.*_update_).*_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.ctr$
```

Here `(?!.*_update_)` is a negative lookahead assertion that fails the match if `_update_` is found after starting `Beta_Gambus_teta_` part.

Comment: The relationship between the two types of paths appears to simply be that `update_` is removed from the positive case.

Comment: Since OP used term `some_changeable_string` I assume it can be anything that may or may not contain `_`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
.+update.+
```